# Blender 2.8 - keyframes not showing?

Tags: materials, keyframes, eevee-render-engine, timeline

I've just started playing around with Blender 2.80 and I'm trying to animate some lightning I did. Whenever I hit 'I' on the Brightness, whether it's at 0 or 1, no keyframe appears on the Timeline.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot

Comment: Don't forget to select "mapping" in below when you want to see keyframes. I did the same mistake :D

Comment: Abigail Z's fantastically simple solution did it for me. D'oh! ®

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Unticking *Only keyframes from Selected Channels* did it for me

Blender 2.91.0

Comment: Could you show how? Perhaps a screenshot of the interface where they are located and an explanation of how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Keyframes not showing is a result of a different texture, material, or any output/input things selected. It will only show if it is specifically selected

Comment: Not sure what this means. Keyframes aren't showing for emission strength in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

In the *Timeline*, go to *View> View All*:

[image: View menu with 'View All' pointed to]

Answer (score 0):

Changing "Dope Sheet" to "Action Editor" in the dropdown menu above the summary did it for me.
[image: Action Editor Location Pic]

Sorry for my terrible drawing skills with a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you'll scroll down in the timeline without knowing, I do it all the time. Just hold down the middle click/ball thing of your mouse and drag down in the timeline to see if this happened. If this is the fix, all your keyframes will appear like magic again.